# How to prevent automount (autofs) changing protection of indirect map mountpoint

Tags: automounting

How do I prevent autofs (automount) from changing the protection of its owned mountpoint.

```
# chmod 2771 /cust
# ls -ld /cust
drwxrws--x. 2 root root 4096 Mar 13 14:43 /cust
# systemctl start autofs
# ls -ld /cust
drwxr-xr-x 332 root root 0 Mar 14 16:26 /cust

# grep cust auto.master
/cust /etc/auto.cust            --ghost
# grep user auto.cust
user :/fs1/cust/&
```

Answer (score 0):

The permissions of the mount point after you mounted your nfs share are the ones of your nfs folder on your nfs server.

you can try to change the permissions on your nfs server:

```
chmod 2771 /fs1/cust
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, it is true that the /fs1 filesystem has drwxr-xr-x

Comment: One other point, the /fs1/cust does have 2771 protection.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit quick to read and saw 
user fs1:/cust/& 
instead of 
user :/fs1/cust/&